# NSURLConnection sometimes truncates the body of an NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, http, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, nsmutableurlrequest

I have an app on the appStore that syncs xml data to a webservice.  I've had two error reports today caused by the xml document ending prematurely.  One ended right in the middle of an xml tag, so I know it isn't a problem caused by special characters.  One of the errors occurred at 184kb, the other at 302kb, so it's not a problem with the request being truncated after so many bytes.  It does seem to only be a problem on longer requests though.

Are there any specific settings that will prevent this truncation from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce this by shutting down my app before the NSURLConnection finishes sending the request.  I'm guessing the same thing was happening with a couple of my app users.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem and haven't been able to track down the problem yet